# Safari extra line in table

Tags: html, css, safari

In my web project i created a simple table and style it with css everything looks normal in chrome firefox and even in ie but in safari, extra border shows up in random table cell and when i select the text in cell, border disappears. There are pictures below. How can i fix this issue ? I guess this is safari issue rather than wrong css or html.

**After page loaded:**
[image]

**After text is selected:**
[image]

Comment: Both images look the same to me!

Comment: look at the selected part extra border disappers when selected

Comment: here it is how it looks after i select and deselect https://dl.dropbox.com/u/47229143/4.png

Comment: Please post your code and/or recreate the problem on jsfiddle.net

Comment: here it is http://jsfiddle.net/ry7L2/1/

Comment: I am in Safari 6.0.2 on OSX and I cannot reproduce that image you posted from your jsfiddle. It's reproducible for you in the fiddle every time?

Comment: I'm in Safari 5.1.7 on Windows 7 and am not able to reproduce the issue in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks valid to me. Infact I am using safari v6.02 and render no errors. Perhaps it may be coming from other html that was not posted.

Side note.. Use safaris element inspector to try and find the problem

Comment: I dont think that this is caused by the otter html because it still renders wrong in jsfiddle on my safari. I have tried to use inspect element but tricky part is when i select <td> border disappears. Im also using 6.0.2 on a Mac Computer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your css for that particular cell (or all of them):

```
td:focus, td:active, td:hover, td{
    border: none;
}
```

Only use the code for the <td>'s that you don't want any border on.

If the above doesn't work, use this:

```
td:before, td:after{
    border: none;
}
```